# Recursion for the Bessel polynomial $y_n(x)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, integer-sequences, recurrences

- Let $a(n)$ be [A001515](https://oeis.org/A001515) i.e. the Bessel polynomial $y_n(x)$ evaluated at $x=1$. Here
  $$
  a(n) = (2n-1)a(n-1) + a(n-2), \\
  a(0) = 1, a(1) = 2
  $$
  The closed form is
  $$
  a(n)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+k}{2k}\frac{(2k)!}{k!2^k}
  $$
  Also exponential generating function is
  $$
  \frac{\exp(1-\sqrt{1-2x})}{\sqrt{1-2x}}
  $$
  and generating function using continued fraction is $\frac{1}{G(0)}$ where
  $$
  G(j)=1-x-\frac{(j+1)x}{G(j+1)}
  $$
- Let
  $$
  R(n,q)=(q+1)R(n-1,q+1)+\sum\limits_{j=0}^{q}(j+1)R(n-1,j), \\
  R(0,q)=1
  $$

I conjecture that
$$R(n,0)=a(n).$$

Here is the PARI/GP prog to check it numerically:

```
a_upto(n)=my(v1); v1=vector(n+1, i, 0); v1[1]=1; v1[2]=2; for(i=2, n, v1[i+1]=(2*i-1)*v1[i] + v1[i-1]); v1
R_upto(n)=my(v1, v2, v3); v1=vector(n+1, i, 1); v2=v1; v3=vector(n+1, i, 0); v3[1]=1; for(i=1, n, for(q=0, n-i, v2[q+1]=(q+1)*v1[q+2] + sum(j=0, q, (j+1)*v1[j+1])); v1=v2; v3[i+1]=v1[1]); v3
test(n)=a_upto(n)==R_upto(n)
```

---

**UPD:**

- Let $T(n,k)$ be [A001498](https://oeis.org/A001498), i.e., triangle of coefficients of Bessel polynomials $y_n(x)$. Here
  $$
  T(n,k)=\frac{(n+k)!}{2^k(n-k)!k!}
  $$
- Let
  $$
  R_1(n,q,z)=(q+1)zR_1(n-1,q+1,z)+\sum\limits_{j=0}^{q}(jz+1)R_1(n-1,j,z), \\
  R_1(0,q,z)=1
  $$

I conjecture that
$$T(n,k)=[z^k]R_1(n,0,z)$$

Here is the PARI/GP prog to check it numerically:

```
T(n, k)=if(k<0||k>n, 0, binomial(n, k)*(n+k)!/2^k/n!)
y(n)=sum(j=0, n, x^j*T(n,j))
R1_upto(n)=my(v1, v2, v3); v1=vector(n+1, i, 1); v2=v1; v3=vector(n+1, i, 0); v3[1]=1; for(i=1, n, for(q=0, n-i, v2[q+1]=(q+1)*x*v1[q+2] + sum(j=0, q, (j*x+1)*v1[j+1])); v1=v2; v3[i+1]=v1[1]); v3
test1(n)=vector(n+1, i, y(i-1))==R1_upto(n)
```

---

Is there a way to prove it?

Comment: Maybe try applying your recursion algorithm to https://oeis.org/A001497 or https://oeis.org/A119274. A001497 is a Sheffer polynomial sequence with lowering and raising operators as indicated in the pdf at https://tcjpn.wordpress.com/2023/07/04/the-umbral-compositional-inverse-of-a-sheffer-polynomial-sequence-and-its-lowering-and-raising-operators/.  The raising op for A119274 is even simpler since it is a binomial Sheffer sequence.